Difference from the first row but aggregating from second row till the end
I have two columns where in the first row (inspection), there are some violations that are spotted and noted... can be 15+ different violations.
Then on every subsequent inspection, there can be some violations that are completed (those that are resolved can NOT show again as unresolved). Number can vary and can even be that inspection didn't see any of remaining violations resolved so for that one it would be an empty row but still has to be counted.



Inspection
Date
Violation




1
6/1/2024
100


1
6/1/2024
101


1
6/1/2024
102


1
6/1/2024
103


2
6/2/2024
100


2
6/2/2024
101


3
6/7/2024
NULL


4
6/8/2024
103


5
6/9/2024
102



What I need as a result are unresolved violations after each inspection ...

I need this in T-SQL. I know how to use LAG, LEAD, FIRST_VALUE etc. Saying that as I tried to resolve it via window funcs. I have created func to get difference between the values (like violations remaining - violations in inspection) but really what I can't figure is how to move past 2nd inspection
Those are aggregates of the tables beneath and if you have some kind of advice I can go and change queries that bring data in this format. Only thing is that for an inspection I do not have recorded answers for each of violations spotted on first but only one that is cleared/resolved
Thanks in advance
SELECT aggdata.Inspection
     , RemainingViolations =
                            CASE
                                WHEN aggdata.Inspection = 1 THEN aggdata.AggregatedViolations
                                ELSE dbo.udf_GetDifferenceInValues(FIRST_VALUE(aggdata.AggregatedViolations) OVER (ORDER BY aggdata.Inspection), aggdata.AggregatedViolations)
                            END
FROM (
    SELECT SimpleData.Inspection
         , AggregatedViolations = STRING_AGG(SimpleData.Violation, ',')
    FROM (VALUES (1, '6/1/2024', 100),
    (1, '6/1/2024', 101),
    (1, '6/1/2024', 102),
    (1, '6/1/2024', 103),
    (2, '6/1/2024', 100),
    (2, '6/1/2024', 101),
    (3, '6/1/2024', NULL),
    (4, '6/1/2024', 103),
    (5, '6/1/2024', 102)
    ) AS
    SimpleData (Inspection, DateInspection, Violation)
    GROUP BY SimpleData.Inspection
) aggdata

ALTER FUNCTION udf_GetDifferenceInValues
(
      -- Add the parameters for the function here
      @String1 VARCHAR(4000)
    , @String2 VARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(4000)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here

    SELECT @Result = STRING_AGG(Value, ',')
    FROM dbo.dbSplit(@String1, ',')
    WHERE Value NOT IN (
            SELECT Value
            FROM dbo.dbSplit(@String2, ',')
        )


    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result
END


As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Please show (not as images), sample/raw data before query and desired results after query.

I have a child table ... what I posted was string aggregates I get per inspection just to show easier what I want to achieve

Right. I understand. Thanks! Added simple data

I think you missed the bit about not using images - use table markdown as supported by the editor

Show what you have tried and your ONE challenge with that so we can help you fix it.

Added what I got so far. Not having a solution on how to eliminate violations row by row from what was left on previous inspection.

/* *** Test Data *** */
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    Inspection int NOT NULL
    ,[Date] date NOT NULL
    ,Violation int NULL
);
INSERT INTO #t
VALUES (1, '20240601', 100)
,(1, '20240601', 101)
,(1, '20240601', 102)
,(1, '20240601', 103)
,(2, '20240602', 100)
,(2, '20240602', 101)
,(3, '20240607', NULL)
,(4, '20240608', 103)
,(5, '20240609', 102);
/* *** End Test Data *** */

WITH vCounts
AS
(
    SELECT X.Inspection, T.Violation AS AViolation, T2.Violation
        ,COUNT(T2.Violation) OVER (PARTITION BY T.Violation ORDER BY X.Inspection ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS VCount
    FROM #t T
        JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Inspection
            FROM #t
        ) X (Inspection)
            ON T.Inspection = 1
        LEFT JOIN #t T2
            ON X.Inspection = T2.Inspection
                AND T.Violation = T2.Violation
)
,VGroups
AS
(
    SELECT Inspection
        ,STRING_AGG(Violation, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY AViolation) AS Violations
        ,STRING_AGG(IIF(Violation IS NULL AND VCount = 1, AViolation, NULL), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY AViolation) AS ActiveViolations
    FROM VCounts
    GROUP BY Inspection
)
SELECT Inspection, Violations
    ,IIF(Inspection = 1, Violations, ActiveViolations) AS ActiveViolations
FROM VGroups
ORDER BY Inspection;


Thank you, sir. This works as I need it to. Now I just need to understand it and apply to the much bigger table I have. Thanks again!

A good answer contains an explanation in addition to a working query
